# Spring Boot MySQL Docker ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot application that depends on a MySQL database in docker-compose. After issuing docker-compose up, I'm getting:

[image]

I'm running on MacOS Ventura 13.0.1, my Docker Compose version is 2.13.0 my Docker version is 20.10.21.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypass

# Hibernate configuration
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
    
services:
  springboot-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
  mysqldb:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    hostname: localhost
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_example
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-11-slim
WORKDIR .
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean install
CMD ["java", "-jar", "target/app.jar"]
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>autopark</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>autopark</name>
    <description>autopark</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>23.2.6</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20220924</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.bootstrapcss</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap-for-vaadin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>frontend</id>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Comment: you are missing this one spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: can you please show the full log

Comment: I don't think mysqldb is the hostname of your db. Try adding "hostname: mysqldb" to your db service. Otherwise try setting MYSQL_HOST to localhost.

Comment: Can you please share pom.xml file

Comment: @SergeiKrainyukov don't you think `springboot-app` container depends on `mysqldb` and thus `mysqldb` container must start first? https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: @SergeiKrainyukov just wondering but did you even try what i said that you are missing one line on the application.properties?

Comment: @Anon Yes, unfortunately It has no effect.

Comment: @Nicolas125841 It hasn't any effect

Comment: ok its prob your database that is not being created before the program is running

Comment: @Anon I checked it in terminal, and the database operates independently of my application.

Comment: your docker-compose.yml say other wise and your logs also say you dont have connecting to db

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250844/discussion-between-sergei-krainyukov-and-anon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution.

**application.properties**

```
# MySQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/autopark
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

# JPA
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim-buster
COPY "/target/app-0.0.6.jar" .
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app-0.0.6.jar"]
```

**docker-compose**

```
version: "3"

services:
  mysqldb:
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: autopark
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mypass

  spring_boot:
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    container_name: spring-app
    image: springboot
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/autopark
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
```

For build target of my project I use command:

```
mvn clean package -Pproduction
```